# meta data on As400 (IBM i) SQL table QSYS2.SYSTABLES

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am looking at meta data on As400 (IBM i) SQL table QSYS2.SYSTABLES.
Table text (description) seems to be encrypted. Any way to read this column?

```
SELECT substr(TABLE_NAME,1,10) TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TEXT FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES                                              

TABLE_NAME  TABLE_TEXT                              
DSPUSRPRF    ë ? Ê È Ñ Á   À Á   à ë & í ë ê & ê ã  
GROUPEPRF    ë ? Ê È Ñ Á   À Á   à ë & í ë ê & ê ã  
LOGIN2       ë ? Ê È Ñ Á   À Á   à ë & í ë ê & ê ã
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TABLE_TEXT is NVARCHAR.
cast to VARCHAR to have in your language :

```
SELECT substr(TABLE_NAME,1,10) TABLE_NAME,
cast(TABLE_TEXT as varchar(50)) 
FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

What emulator are you using?

IBM's [Access Client Solutions](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-client-solutions) should handle NVARCHAR just fine...
And also provides a Run SQL Scripts which is a better option than STRSQL.

The old Client Access for Windows does not handle NVARCHAR.

If using a third party emulation, check with your vendor.

Comment: I was using JDBC driver and NVARCHAR was displaying almost fine but without accents. My table description are in French. Perhaps there's a jdbc option in the connection url to display naturally NVARCHAR without casting

Comment: What client?  ACS Run SQL Scripts uses JDBC should have handled it just fine.

Comment: I was using an old version of squirrelSQL with an old jt400 driver.   Updated both and display of NVARCHAR is OK without casting. No jdbc properties needed.  I don't know if the parsing of NVARCHAR is to be done by the client or the JDBC driver.